# Resource Based Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization

In web application we are currently working on, we have `Company` entity which only the person who created it can edit.

So every time when the `EditCompany` action is called we must check the database and see if the currently logged in user is owner of the company. This is just one example, but we have more permission types other than Owner and more operations with `Company`.

What we did is that at the start of each action we call some service method to see if that user has required permission for that resource, for instance `companyService.HasEditPermission(userId, companyId)` and if that is true we procceed further.

But recently, someone told me that such code shoudlnt be in controller, but a custom Attribute should be created which handles that permission logic and then we just put that Attribute on the controller action. But that person is not `Asp.Net` programmer and he doesnt know how it should be implemented in `Asp.Net`. So my question is, is it possible to do something like that in `Asp.Net` and if it is, how should we implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is, is it possible to do something like that in Asp.Net and if it is, how should we implement that?

Yes, it's perfectly possible and it's a good way to achieve your goal.

To implement this you have to create a custom Filter Attribute that extends the AuthorizeAttribute class and override it's OnAuthorization method. In the overridden method you can check the request parameters (available on filterContext parameter) and fire your authorization logic.